# Access denied mysql rails 4

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I set up a mysql database in a rails 4 app using the following database.yml:

```
default: &default
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  pool: 5
  host: localhost
  username: <%= ENV['MYSQL_USER'] %> 
  password: <%= ENV['MYSQL_PASSWORD'] %>
  socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

development:
  <<: *default
  database: database_development
test:
  <<: *default
  database: database_development
```

At the beginning it worked fine and I didn't have any database problems. I created a few join tables and some `has_many :through` associations and it started to throw the following error:

```
Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) (Mysql2::Error)
```

So, there are some inconsistencies in that error that make me think that rails is not loading well the database.yml file:

- First, if I do any migrations or I start the server, rails doesn't complain and works just fine. The error appears when I try to access a model from the console or when I run **rspec** unit tests.
- Second, the user I set up in the environment variable MYSQL_USER is not root
- And third, when I run `ENV['MYSQL_USER']` and `ENV['MYSQL_PASSWORD']` in the console, they show the right values (the ones I set up in the environment variables).

I understand that for mysql, rails uses `ActiveRecord::Base.connection_config` variable to set up the credentials and some other information to be able to access the database, so I printed it:

```
=> {:adapter=>"mysql2", :encoding=>"utf8", :pool=>5, :host=>"localhost", :username=>nil, :password=>nil, :socket=>"/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock", :database=>"database_development"}
```

As you can see, the credentials are both nil, so, for fixing the access in the console, I just changed the entries `:username` and `password` to the right values, but of course, that is not working for the **rspec** unit tests.

My guess is that rails is not setting up `ActiveRecord::Base.connection_config`, but I don't know how to check this assignment or if any change that I made could possibly modify this behavior.

Comment: It's a little unusual to force things in like this. This configuration file is intended to be self-contained.

Comment: you need to set those vars in test environment, are you doing that? `MYSQL_USER=qwe MYSQL_PASSWORD=asd rspec .`

Comment: I didn't do that @juanpastas (I feel really stupid), but still I don't want to change the connection_config each time I run the console.